# Redirect after logout to the wrong language

Tags: redirect, internationalization, spring-social

I am using spring security and i18n.
My application has 2 languages: Fr and En, Fr being the default one.  However, when I logged in using the English languages and then log out, I will be redirected to the french homepage.  I tried changing the logout url,  including the language part, like this: 
"/login/login.mvc?logout=True?language=i18n_get_lang()"
, but no success. Any idea how to solve this would be more than welcome. 
PS, the login redirection works correctly.

Below is my springSecurity.xml

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">



    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/login.mvc" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" /> -->
        <form-login
            login-processing-url="/login/login.mvc" 
            login-page="/login/login.mvc" 
            default-target-url="/login/accueil.mvc" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login/login.mvc?Error=True" 
            username-parameter="j_username"
            password-parameter="j_password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login/login.mvc?logout=True?language=localeChangeInterceptor" 
                logout-url="/login/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        <!-- unable csrf protection -->
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
          <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
          </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

My MVC-servlet.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
         <property name="basename" value="classpath:i18n/Message"/>
         <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="fr" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
<!-- Changes the locale when a 'lang' request parameter is sent; e.g. /?lang=de -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
      <property name="paramName" value="language"/>
   </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="interceptors">
           <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
           </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: change SessionLocaleResolver to CookieLocaleResolver in MVC-servlet.xml.